# How to get second element in PhantomJS using Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, enzyme

I have a wrapper with four  components, so when I do `console.log(wrapper.find(LabeledInput).debug());`, this is logged:

```
<LabeledInput label="Tenant ID" placeholder="Add a tenant" value="infor" onEnter={[Function]} updateValue={[Function]} />

<LabeledInput label="Store ID" placeholder="Add a store" value="12345" onEnter={[Function]} updateValue={[Function]} />

<LabeledInput label="Server" placeholder="Add account endpoint" value="test" onEnter={[Function]} updateValue={[Function]} />

<LabeledInput label="test Link" placeholder="Add OCH link" value="http://www.test.com/" onEnter={[Function]} updateValue={[Function]} />
```

How can I get the third element from the log above? I tried `console.log(wrapper.find(LabeledInput).childAt(2));` but it fails, saying `Error: Method “childAt” is only meant to be run on a single node. 4 found instead.`

**I'm using Enzyme's Shallow Rendering API.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(wrapper.find('LabeledInput').at(2))` should do the trick.  Notice the quotes around `LabeledInput` as well as using `at`.